# How can I call store procedure in grails and groovy

Tags: grails, stored-procedures, groovy

I have a requirement like calling stored procedure inside groovy and grails. I am using Mongodb for database. 
Can anyone please tell me the step by step to call stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

Aim to do this from a Grails service.

```
// Inject a data source: 
def dataSource //or def dataSource_<other named DS name>

def serviceMethod() {
  Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource_messages)

  def sqlCall = "exec sp_name :param1, :param2"
  final paramMap = [param1: new Timestamp(dateFrom.time), param2: new Timestamp(dateTo.time)]
  log.info "Running: $sqlCall with params $paramMap"
  def rows = []
  try {
      rows = sql.rows(sqlCall, paramMap)
  } catch (Exception e) {
      log.warn "Could not execute ${sqlCall} with params ${paramMap}: ${e.getMessage()}", e
  }
  rows
```

}

Optionally convert to command objects:

```
rows.collect { row -> new MyCmd(row) }

public class MyCmd {
    String spField1
    String spField2
    Date dateTime
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in following way

```
def dataSource 
        def  dataList = []
        Sql sql = Sql.newInstance(dataSource)
        def camp = "Campaign"            
        dataList = sql.rows("{call sp_upldata(?)}",[camp])
        sql.close()
```

here `sp_upldata` is the name of the stored procedure created in database and `camp` stores the data from which result are to be find out .The data obtained by query will be saved in `dataList`. 
The example query of the above will be following in case of plain sql  query

`select * from table_name where table_name.column_name = 'Campaign';`